# Jumpy scrolling on ALPS touchpad

Tags: touchpad, drivers, thinkpad

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad T440 that came with the infamous clackpad. Since that was much of an annoyance, I replaced it with a T540 touchpad - Alps DualPoint TouchPad. Here's the output from `xinput`

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DualPoint Stick                           id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Integrated Camera                         id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I used to run Windows 8.1 and the touchpad worked just fine with multi-finger gestures as well. However, in elementaryOS, only the two-finger scrolling work. That itself is fine but sometimes (let's say every third or fourth scroll) the scrolling starts off extremely jumpy. If I am trying to go down a page, it'll jump all the way up near the start of the page.

Is this a mouse sensitivity issue, driver issue? How can I fix it?

Comment: Here's my answer on a related thread
. http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/6995/5545

Answer (score 1):

You could try to (re)install the `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` package. It helped me with a similiar problem *(other touchpad brand, but yours should be also supported by the synaptic driver)*