# Touchpad shaking

Tags: mouse

I really love elementary OS, but there is a really annoying bug where the mouse shakes when I use my track pad.
It's not a defective track pad, I have installed Ubuntu Mate and had no problems with the mouse.

Comment: This could be related issue and fix https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/6967/how-to-fix-elementaryos-touchpad-problem?rq=1 if this fixes the issue please close this question. Other than that official policy is bug reports need to go on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementary), questions are meant to be closed here and reported to developers directly https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementary That said, there is a [discussion](https://elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232/proposal-lets-not-close-questions-concerning-bugs-feature-requests-as-off-topi) about whether

Comment: Bug reports can't really be resolved via a Q&A site like Stack Exchange, you'd have better luck reporting this on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementary) so the developers can be made aware of it :) Sign up for an account if you don't have one already and then click the 'Report a bug' button in the top right.

Answer (score 1):

I've had problems with my trackpad as well and posted my solution on reddit which you can check here: [Link to Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/8fte94/question_regarding_trackpad_on_xiami_mi_12/). Not sure if it will solve your problem though!

Basically the command I've used looks like this:

> sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

all at once and not split by a new line.